# How to implement setter for exported field in Golang?

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I'm using `gorm` lib and to use that lib, I have to export all column fields. Something like this

```
type myType struct {
  Id int
  Name string
}
```

But with that, how to I deal with addition logics for struct fields. Let's say, what if I want to prefix `Mr` to the `Name` field? The client can always do `myType.Name = "whatever"`. If I make `Name` to be unexported and have setter for it, that field will never work with `gorm`. Any golang-way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct about unexported field with method.

Your `struct` Fields have to be exported then only `gorm` will have access to it. That is Go way.

So you have 2 options.

Option 1: taking advantage of gorm callback [AfterFind](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/callbacks.html#querying-an-object). Basically your struct have to implement this callback. After find you have to update the field `Name`.

Option 2: Implement as part of your data fetch method. Update the field `Name` before returning to the caller.